# Check availability and room booking in PHP MsSQL

Tags: php, mysql

[Previously asked question by a user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12043207/rooms-availability-dates-php-mysql)

Below is the my SQL code.

```
$find=mysqli_query($dbconn,"
SELECT *
  FROM room 
 WHERE room_no NOT IN 
   (SELECT room_no 
    FROM reservation 
   WHERE check_in<='$check_out' 
      AND check_out>='$check_in');
```

Imagine someone has booked room number 100 for 12.07 to 12.10.
Another one search for the 12.10 to 12.12 for same room?
Then it showing no rooms available.
My checkin time for the room is 02.00 pm. Checkout is 10.00 am. So how could I fixed this.

(Eg. Someone has book room no 100 for 12.07 to 12.10. His checkout will be on 12.10 10.00 am. Then another can be booked room no 100 on 12.10 to 12.12. Because his checkin time will be 02.00 pm in 12.10.)

I guess I explained it.

Awaiting for your kind helps.

Thank you.

PS.

```
Room Table
----------
id  room_no  status
1     100      1
2     101      1


Reservation Table
-------------------
id room_no     check_in          check_out
1    100      2020.12.07        2020.12.10
```

I have also tried this sql code also. But same results.

```
$find=mysqli_query($dbconn,"SELECT * FROM room WHERE room_no NOT IN (SELECT room_no FROM reservation WHERE(check_out>='$check_in' AND check_in<='$check_out')OR(check_out<='$check_in' AND check_in>='$check_out'))");
```

Comment: Can you give a sample data for your room and reservation table,  Also the value of `$check_out` and `$check_in` ?

Comment: Hi. Thank for your answer. I have edited the question.

Comment: So you are not considering time in the reservation table? I think you checkin and checkout field type is `DATE`

Comment: Yes. It's date. How can I add the check in time and checkout time and check for it?

Comment: Make your check_in and check_out filed type as datetime or timestamp  so you can store time also along with date. So at first do this

Comment: Your code is incomplete

Comment: Minute by minute booking of rooms is a little unusual

Comment: @Strawberry Hi can you kindly suggest a correct code snippet for me?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to allow check out and check in on the same day, you just have to allow the ranges to meet up;  Change `<=` to `<` and change `>=` to `>`.